# Why are people leaving out the indefinite article 'a' before seemingly random nouns?

Tags: grammatical-number, participles

I've heard mostly British English people say 'He went to hospital' or 'She is matriculated at university'. I've never understood this but accepted it as a quirk of the language like so many others.

Lately I've heard instances on the radio where this has been applied to seemingly random nouns. The example I heard this morning was: "When a company builds factory abroad..". To me it feels like this is turning the singular 'factory' into a collective noun like the word weather or water. I don't think these are all human speech/language errors because I've heard this in other cases as well, not to mention the one's i've already known about like hospital and university.

Can someone explain the rules around this feature?

Comment: It's more bug than feature.

Comment: In British English, if you *"go to hospital"*, *"go to university"*, *"go to church"*, or *"go to prison"*, you are a patient, a student, a worshipper, or an inmate there. If you *"go to the hospital"*, you are not a patient, but could be a visitor.

Comment: On the other hand *build factory* is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: She went to hospital, went to work, went to school, went to university. The rule here would be leaving off the article when it's an institution and not the specific school or university that's being focussed on. On the other example I imagine the 'a' got swallowed in the pronunciation.

Comment: What radio? The BBC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, when you are talking about a place being attended *as an institution*, we often leave out the article; but the choice of which institutions you can do this with varies according to the variety of English.

So in British and American English we say *to/in prison* and *to school* (though there is another difference in the preposition: AmE *in school*, AmE/BrE *at school*). But British English says *to/in hospital* where American English says *to/in the hospital* (even if this is not in reference to a particular hospital).

It's not just geographical varieties either: there is a significant number of instances of *at conference* in the GloWbE corpus - more for UK and New Zealand than the US: these are predominantly in the world of politics and unions, and little used outside those fields.

Your example with "factory" is not idiomatic in any variety of English as far as I know, and I would suppose that it is either a mistake, or written by a non-native writer.

Comment: AmE says in school and at school. Otherwise, OK.

Comment: @Lambie: I didn't realise AmE said _at school_. We don't say _in school_ in BrE. Edited.

Comment: "I was at school or in school in Colorado".

Comment: @ColinFine I would say that the AmE *in school* is occupational; she's still in school, he's only in primary school, they're in college at Yale. This is not unlike being *in retirement* or *in medicine*. In contrast, *in church* means you are *at church* but *in* organized worship services—which is kind of like being *at work*, as opposed to *in work*. Blerg, English. Someone should be thrown in jail.

Comment: Whereas in BrE, @choster, _in church_ (like _in school_) tends to mean just that you are physically in the building; but for taking part in a service, we are more likely to say _at church_.

Comment: That's a very ironic edit message

Answer (score 0):

Because the nouns in those instances are being used as [noncount nouns](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-understanding-noncount-nouns/3193621.html).  Noncount nouns are nouns that are neither singular nor plural but are treated as singular for verb conjugation but as plural for article application (e.g., "...information is," not "information *are*" or "*an* information is").

In British English, the noun "hospital" is used as a noncount noun unless referring to a specific hospital.

American English, though, does use "university" as a nouncount noun in such contexts, although it's far more common in the American vernacular to say "college" (e.g., Where a Brit might say, "She is matriculated at university," an American would generally say, "She's enrolled in college," notably not "She's enrolled in *a* college" unless the speaker is expressly conveying that the particular college she's enrolled in is more than merely unspecified but is unknown, insignificant, or random.).

I can't speak to "factory" being used as a noncount noun because I've never heard that.  I can speak to plenty of other nouns that are used that way, like "work," "church," and "home."  I can speak to plenty of nouns that aren't, like "store," "pub," and "club."  I mean, if I'm a church member going to attend a church meeting at my church, I say, "I'm going to church," but if I'm a club member going to attend a club meeting at my club, I say, "I'm going to *the* club," so there is some arbitrariness to what place nouns are noncount nouns and what place nouns are count nouns.

Comment: I can't imagine any Brit saying _She is matriculated at university_. If there is some reason why the formal process of matriculation needs to be mentioned, then we would say _She has matriculated_, but I'm not sure what preposition we would follow it with. Normally we'd say _She's at university_ or _She's studying at university_.

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced this is about count vs. noncount. Noncount nouns sometimes take _the_: "He's fallen in the water".

Comment: This is an aspect I have known about (weather) but in cases like the ones i mentioned (to hostpital) a person is going to a specific, concrete singular place.